# Masking countermeasures for AES-GCM

Tags: implementation, side-channel-attack, aes-gcm

Suppose I have a masked AES encryption $AES(\oplus_i K_i, \oplus_i P_i)=\oplus_i C_i$, i.e. the key, plaintext, and resulting ciphertext are tuples $K_i$, $P_i$, and $C_i$ that sum to $K$, $P$, and $C$ respectively, and the encryption acts independently on the randomized input shares to the extent possible to produce the output shares.  Cf. [Threshold Implementations Against Side-Channel Attacks and Glitches](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/11935308_38) or similar.

While there is much literature on implementing the sbox or single block (en/de)cryption, there is much less on protecting modes of operation or managing hardware in operation.  Consider the following situations.

- A static key is already expanded and split into shares.  How often should I refresh the masks on the round keys (assuming incoming data blocks are freshly masked)?
- Suppose the masked cipher is being used in GCM (cf. [NIST SP 800-38D](https://csrc.nist.gov/pubs/sp/800/38/d/final).

  - A static key is already expanded and split into shares, and the initial counter block $ICB=IV\|(2\bmod 2^{32})$ is shared (say added to a sharing of $0^{128}$).  Should I refresh the randomness on the round keys?  Should I refresh randomness on the counter blocks or can I use the same masks (and only increment the counter)?  Is it worth doing both?  It seems that addRoundKey would make updating both masks obsolete.
  - GHASH is linear for a fixed hash key $H=\text{enc}_K(0^{128})$, so it could be separately evaluated on shares.  However, we could also mask the $GF(2^{128})$ multiplier, splitting both the input and hash key.  Is there good reason to do the latter and not the former?

Comment: To me it's not quite clear what you mean by "masked AES Encryption $AES(\oplus_i K_i, \oplus_i P_i) = \oplus_i C_i$". I have not encountered the term before. The notation $\oplus_i A_i$ probably stands for $A_1 \oplus A_2 \oplus \ldots \oplus A_k$, but then I am unsure what the sets $(K_i)$, $(P_i)$ and $(C_i)$ are. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Morrolan Edited.  Basically input is "split" into random "shares" and cryptographic operations are performed independently on the shares to the extent possible so as to decouple side-channels from secret information.  For AES, most of the round function is linear (shiftRows, mixColumns, addRoundKey) but the sbox inversion is non-linear and requires special care, usually randomness in addition to the initial split.  My question is about handling some of this in the larger context of AES-GCM.